# Android Studio + Andy: не удается запустить эмулятор в режиме отладки приложения

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор

Всем доброго дня, коллеги!
Ситуация следующая: установил эмулятор Andy. Запускаю в Android Studio дебаггер, вижу Andy в Device Chooser, выбираю. В окне дебаггера, где отображаются логи, получаю сообщение:

> Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application
>   using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse

Реальное устройство отключено. Если открыть Andy, то можно увидеть, что приложение стартовало, но при этом висит модальное окно с текстом:

> Application X is waiting for the debugger to attach

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться в причине демарша.

Answer (score 1):

Коллеги, все оказалось весьма прозаичным: помогла перезагрузка студии. Все заработало сразу.